# Access report to Excel with bold border lines?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have an Access program that takes 2 different related exported csv reports from the ERP and reads them and created on excel output. I would like to have the excel have better grid lines known in 'Format Cells' then 'Border' then hit 'Outline' and 'Inside' this makes it easier to read.

I would like to if I can add this to my code shown that creates the excel output.

```
Do Until mydeptset.EOF
            mypos = mydeptset.AbsolutePosition
            If mypos > 0 Then
                If Int(mypos / 10) > 0 Then
                    If mypos Mod 10 = 0 Then
                        m = 2
                        n = k + 5
                        .Activate
                         .Range("A1:AF5").Select
                         myxls.Selection.Copy

                         .Range("A" & CStr(n)).Select
                         .Paste
                         .Range("A" & n + 3 & ":AF" & CStr(n + 3)).Clear
                         mydtset.MoveFirst
                         n = n + 5
                         k = n
                         Do Until mydtset.EOF
                            .Cells(k, 1) = mydtset!dt
                            mydtset.MoveNext
                            k = k + 1
                        Loop
                        .Cells(k, 1) = "Tot"
                        .Cells(k, 1).HorizontalAlignment = 2
                        .Cells(k, 1).Font.Bold = True
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                n = 4
                 mydtset.MoveFirst
                 m = 2
                k = 6
                Do Until mydtset.EOF
                    .Cells(k, 1) = mydtset!dt
                    mydtset.MoveNext
                    k = k + 1
                Loop
                .Cells(k, 1) = "Tot"
                .Cells(k, 1).HorizontalAlignment = 2
                .Cells(k, 1).Font.Bold = True
            End If
            If n = 4 Then
                k = 4
            Else
                k = n - 2
            End If
                .Cells(k, m) = mydeptset!drname
                With .Cells(k, m)
                    .Font.Bold = True
                    .Font.Size = 8
                    .HorizontalAlignment = 1
                End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Range("A1:B6").Borders.LineStyle=1
```